# Datagrid binding several properties of one object to column

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, model-view

I have an object with several properties. However some of these properties contain information of the same group so to say. I would like to show these properties in a table in a way that in the same column i could put the properties of the same group. However I am not sure how to do that exactly. I do understand how to do it if i had several objects of the same type (put them in a list and get the default collection view source). But in this case i just have one object with several properties.

My question is: how could I bring these properties together to make one column in datagrid. all the properties are of same datatype (ushort).

Just to illustrate what i mean:

```
public ushort MyProperty1
{
    get{ return myProperty1}
    set
    {
       if(value==myProperty1)
         return;
       myProperty1=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty1");    
    }
}

public ushort MyProperty2
{
    get{ return myProperty2}
    set
    {
       if(value==myProperty2)
         return;
       myProperty2=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty2");    
    }
}

public ushort MyProperty3
{
    get{ return myProperty3}
    set
    {
       if(value==myProperty3)
         return;
       myProperty3=value;
       OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty3");    
    }
}
```

And i would like to show these properties in the same column of datagrid

Thanks :)

Comment: A custom `DataGridCellTemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few options to acieve your goal. You could use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a `StringFormat` in a standard `DataGridTextColumn`.

Alternatively, you could define a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it as the [`CellTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of a `DataGridTemplateColumn` element.

I've included links to help get you started.

Comment: Oh. data template looks like just the thing i need to make it decent :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can try the below one

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Values">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty1}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty2}"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty3}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: yeah. i was thinking about it. it's just that i have several of these tables and each has some 16 in 3 columns. so it's a bit of a mess in this case :) but thanks anyway ;)